# Let f and g are homotopic chain maps of (C,d)

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let $f$ and $g$ are homotopic chain maps  of $(C,d)$, then $f_{*n}=g_{*n}: H_{n}(X) \to H_{n}(X')$. Can you give me the example showing that the converse is not true?

Comment: You mean where a collection of maps between homology groups that is not equal to the induced collection from a chain map?

Comment: I just posted an example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833135/if-two-chain-maps-over-a-pid-induce-the-same-homomorphism-then-they-are-homotop/1834547#1834547

Comment: Thank you so much :) But I do not know your notation (2 1) mean? @iwriteonbananas

Comment: This is the map $\Bbb Z^2\to \Bbb Z$ defined on a basis by $(1,0)\mapsto 2$ and $(0,1)\to 1$

Comment: And (2) mean $x$ becomes $2x$, right?